# Doesnot '[.\n]' represent any character?

Tags: python, regex

```
content = 'abcdd'


import re,os,sys
def test():
    print content
    list = re.findall(r'[.\n]+',content)
    print list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

I know '.' represent any charaters except '\n'

so [.\n] should  represent any characters

but the result is []

why

can you help me ?

thank you in avdanvce !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.` inside character class `[]` loses its special meaning of "all characters (except newline or not depending on flag)" and is only a plain full stop `.`.

So `[.\n]` only matches full stop `.` or new line character.

If you want to match any character (without exception), one trick is to form a character class of complementing character classes, e.g. `[\s\S]`. This is useful when the regular expression of the language doesn't support DOTALL option, which makes `.` matches any character.

**However**, since Python supports DOTALL option ([`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)), so you can make use of it.

Note that for Python, `.` excludes only `\n`. For other languages, it may excludes more: [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 1):

to get everything:

```
content = 'abcdd'

import re,os,sys
def test():
    print content
    list = re.findall(r'.+', content, re.DOTALL)
    print list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

results:

```
>>> 
abcdd
['abcdd']
```

you need to use DOTALL (which means `.` will also mean `\n`)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets. For
>   example, [(+*)]  will match any of the literal characters '(', '+',
>   '*', or ')'.

Try using `'.|\n'` instead, or, as specified before, re.DOTALL.